# How to set default dropdown value from in Blazor

Tags: select, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

recently i am playing around with blazor-pizza shops tutorial.
I think of something to fix here.

**Current:**
American bacon is my first selection, after i selected it, the dropdownlist is selecting Artichoke hearts

**Outcome I want:**
Dropdownlist to reset default selecting "(select)" after i select the American bacon

[image: dropdownscreenshot]

My code like this:

```
@inject HttpClient HttpClient

@code {
List<Topping> toppings;

[Parameter] public Pizza Pizza { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback OnCancel { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback OnConfirm { get; set; }
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    toppings = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Topping>>("toppings");
}

void ToppingSelected(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (int.TryParse((string)e.Value, out var index) && index >= 0)
    {
        AddTopping(toppings[index]);
        toppings.Remove(toppings[index]);
    }
}

void AddTopping(Topping topping)
{
    if (Pizza.Toppings.Find(pt => pt.Topping == topping) == null)
    {
        Pizza.Toppings.Add(new PizzaTopping() { Topping = topping });
    }
}

void RemoveTopping(Topping topping)
{
    Pizza.Toppings.RemoveAll(pt => pt.Topping == topping);
    toppings.Add(topping);
    toppings = toppings.OrderBy(p=>p.Name).ToList();
}
}
<div class="dialog-container">
<div class="dialog">
    <div class="dialog-title">
        <h2>@Pizza.Special.Name</h2>
        @Pizza.Special.Description
    </div>
    <form class="dialog-body">
        <div>
            <label>Size:</label>
                <input type="range" min="@Pizza.MinimumSize" max="@Pizza.MaximumSize" step="1" @bind="Pizza.Size" @bind:event="oninput" />
            <span class="size-label">
                @(Pizza.Size)" (£@(Pizza.GetFormattedTotalPrice()))
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Extra Toppings:</label>
            @if (toppings == null)
            {
                <select class="custom-select" disabled>
                    <option>(loading...)</option>
                </select>
            }
            else if (Pizza.Toppings.Count >= 6)
            {
                <div>(maximum reached)</div>
            }
            else
            {
                <select id="ToppingSelection" class="custom-select" @onchange="ToppingSelected">
                    <option value="-1" disabled selected>(select)</option>
                    @for (var i = 0; i < toppings.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <option value="@i">@toppings[i].Name - (£@(toppings[i].GetFormattedPrice()))</option>
                    }
                </select>
            }
        </div>

        <div class="toppings">
            @foreach (var topping in Pizza.Toppings)
            {
                <div class="topping">
                    @topping.Topping.Name
                    <span class="topping-price">@topping.Topping.GetFormattedPrice()</span>
                    <button type="button" class="delete-topping" @onclick="@(() => RemoveTopping(topping.Topping))">x</button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="dialog-buttons">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary mr-auto" @onclick="OnCancel">Cancel</button>
        <span class="mr-center">
            Price: <span class="price">@(Pizza.GetFormattedTotalPrice())</span>
        </span>
        <button class="btn btn-success ml-auto" @onclick="OnConfirm">Order ></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend rewriting the form to use the built-in Blazor components like `InputSelect` with proper two-way binding etc.

However, a "quick" fix could be something like *a static binding*. First, create a field that always has a value of `-1` which is your code for `(select)`

```
@code {
 private readonly Int32 _toppingsIndex = -1;
}
```

In the next step, set the value to the select control.

```
<select id="ToppingSelection" class="custom-select" 
        @onchange="ToppingSelected"
        value="@_toppingsIndex">
                    <option value="-1" disabled>(select)</option>
                    @for (var i = 0; i < toppings.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <option value="@i">@toppings[i].Name - (£@(toppings[i].GetFormattedPrice()))</option>
                    }
</select>
```

### Explanation

As soon as you select something, your method `ToppingSelected` is executed, and the topping is removed from the list. As soon as the method has finished, a new render cycle is started. The value is still `-1`, so the option with the value `-1` will be selected after the rendering is finished.